# python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully on deployment to heroku

Tags: python, heroku, pip

I upgraded my pip version after deploying and hosting my website. Then i installed a new package pypaystack. when i attempt to push to heroku i get the error below. Project works fine in development stage.

```
  Collecting pypaystack==1.24
remote:          Downloading pypaystack-1.24.tar.gz (5.4 kB)
remote:          Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
remote:          Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
remote:          error: subprocess-exited-with-error
remote:
remote:          × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
remote:          │ exit code: 1
remote:          ╰─> [12 lines of output]
remote:              Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:                File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
remote:                File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
remote:                File "/tmp/pip-install-h6ay7jb3/pypaystack_2a3b97aa3d934da4b6c7a7d81a4a6ad2/setup.py", line 2, in <module>
remote:                  from pypaystack import version
remote:                File "/tmp/pip-install-h6ay7jb3/pypaystack_2a3b97aa3d934da4b6c7a7d81a4a6ad2/pypaystack/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
remote:                  from .customers import Customer
remote:                File "/tmp/pip-install-h6ay7jb3/pypaystack_2a3b97aa3d934da4b6c7a7d81a4a6ad2/pypaystack/customers.py", line 1, in <module>
remote:                  from .baseapi import BaseAPI
remote:                File "/tmp/pip-install-h6ay7jb3/pypaystack_2a3b97aa3d934da4b6c7a7d81a4a6ad2/pypaystack/baseapi.py", line 2, in <module>
remote:                  import requests
remote:              ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
remote:              [end of output]
remote:
remote:          note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
remote:        error: metadata-generation-failed
remote:
remote:        × Encountered error while generating package metadata.
remote:        ╰─> See above for output.
remote:
remote:        note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
remote:        hint: See above for details.
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
```

What can be the issue? I even created a new virtual environment but the error remains.

Comment: does your requirements,txt have request library?

Comment: Yes it does. When i uninstalled pypaystack it works fine.